# Prevent iframe js from auto scrolling the parent page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We have a page that has a video on it, embedded with an iframe.

The iframe js code for the player has the following code in it:

```
m.default.focus(function (e) {
          var t = e.playButton;
          (0, y.focusElement) (t)
        })
```

This basically makes the play button visible on the screen if it isn't already. Which is fine for stand alone videos, but not on a page where we have the video embedded.

What it does framed in on our page is cause the entire page to scroll to that content.

We'd like to prevent that if possible.

Here is the iframe code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive mb-5 embed-responsive-16by9" id="myFrame" style="height: auto;">
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" class="embed-responsive-item" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-downloads-without-user-activation allow-same-origin" src="https://sourcefile.onthesamedomain.com" title="Video"></iframe>
</div>
```

We've tried the scroll to 0,0 on the parent but that didn't work.

Apologies, but I forgot to add that this is only an issue in Firefox. The other browsers work with the attributes on the iframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd party owner of the js within the iframe ended up providing a fix. There was no way we could do this without the screen scrolling back and forth.